# Not able to access session variables outside scope of portlet in liferay 7

Tags: java, liferay

I am converting my liferay 6 custom porlets into liferay 7. These portlets are deployed in WAR style. 
Portlets getting deployed successfully but, not able to access session variables outside the scope of portlets, even if the variables are in APPLICATION_SCOPE.

These portlets are working fine on liferay 6.2.

Is there any changes i have to make in portlet for liferay 7?

Best regards,
Kiran

Comment: Can you share the code for setting and getting session attributes?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `outside the scope`? Are you trying to get that attribute in another portlet or at portal level?

Comment: i am accessing attribute in another portlet. Here is the code, for setting portletSession.setAttribute("LIFERAY_SHARED_HELLO", "hello",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE)  and for getting portletSession.getAttribute("LIFERAY_SHARED_HELLO", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE). I am getting null here.

Comment: and also  set <private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes> in both portlets.

Comment: What does it return, when you get it from session after the point you are setting it.

Comment: if i access it within same portlet it return the correct value.

Comment: And do have set `<private-session-attributes>false</private-session-attributes>` in second portlet as well?

Comment: yes. set in both portlets.

Comment: I happily haven't used Liferay for the past 2 years, and certainly not the v7,  but maybe try to log *all* the available session attribute names, maybe the namespace prefix changed or sth?

Answer (score 0):

it's strange that it work before but according to docs it's possibile to share form portal to portlet and not from portlet to portlet using LIFERAY_SHARED.

> Portlets that have been configured to use private session attributes
>   in liferay-portlet.xml may still want to share some session
>   attributes. This property allows you to configure which session
>   attributes will be shared. Set a comma delimited list of attribute
>   names that will be shared when the attribute name starts with one of
>   the specified attribute names. For example, if you set the value to
>   "hello_,world_", then all attribute names that start with "hello_" or
>   "world_" will be shared.
>
> **Note that this property is used to specify the sharing of session
>   attributes from the portal to the portlet. This is not used to specify
>   session sharing between portlet WARs or from the portlet to the
>   portal.**